# What does a stand-alone question mark do in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I use the conditional operator (? :) in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252936/how-do-i-use-the-conditional-operator-in-ruby)

I'm teaching myself Ruby and going through the RubyMonk exercises.  I came across this code, which confuses me:

```
def calculate(*arguments)
  options = arguments[-1].is_a?(Hash) ? arguments.pop : {}
  options[:add] = true if options.empty?
  return add(*arguments) if options[:add]
  return subtract(*arguments) if options[:subtract]
end
```

Note that add and subtract are existing functions that add/subtract its arguments, which could vary in length.

Calculate is supposed to work like this

```
 calculate(1,2,3,4,5,add: true) => 10
 calculate(10,3,4, subtract: true) => 3
```

My question is can someone explain what is happening in the line:

```
options = arguments[-1].is_a?(Hash) ? arguments.pop : {}
```

Namely, what exactly does a standalone question mark do?  Also, what does the colon do?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: It's part of the ternary operator.  See here:http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm under Ternary Operator.

Answer (score 6):

```
options = arguments[-1].is_a?(Hash) ? arguments.pop : {}
```

Is part of a ternary operator statement. It is a way to do an if conditional on a single line.

```
(condition) ? then : else.
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 3):

It's an alternative way to express if-then-else. For example

```
options = arguments[-1].is_a?(Hash) ? arguments.pop : {}
```

is exactly the same as

```
if arguments[-1].is_a?(Hash)
  options = arguments.pop
else
  options = {}
end
```

Comment: This was also a helpful comment. Thanks.