# Using "? return :"

Tags: ruby

Below is part of a Ruby function that checks for a specific directory and creates it if it does not already exist:

```
if Dir.exists?(dir_name) == false
  Dir.mkdir(dir_name)
end
```

I understand that there is a shorter way of doing the exact same thing:

```
Dir.exists?(dir_name) ? return : Dir.mkdir(dir_name)
```

However, I can't quite make sense of this.  The important part of the second command is `? return :`.  The first part of the command has the parameter to check, and the last part has the action to take, but I can't make sense of `? return :`.  If I wanted the action in the last part of the command to execute if and only if `dir_name` *did* already exist, what would I use instead of `? return :`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use the conditional operator (? :) in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252936/how-do-i-use-the-conditional-operator-in-ruby)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use

```
Dir.mkdir(dir_name) unless Dir.exists?(dir_name)
```

---

`unless <statement>` is the same as `if !<statement>`. Remember never to make a statement that compares a boolean value to another boolean.

For example, increasing readability of your first statement

```
if Dir.exists?(dir_name) == false

if !Dir.exists?(dir_name)

unless Dir.exists?(dir_name)
```

---

The line `Dir.exists?(dir_name) ? return : Dir.mkdir(dir_name)` uses the [ternary operator](http://ruby.about.com/od/beginningruby/a/The-Ternary-Or-Conditional-Operator.htm).

`return` immediately exits the function, usually returning a value like `return "some value"` but you can also just call `return` to exit the function and return `nil`.

Long story short the ternary version breaks the function if the dir exists, so nothing after that in the function would happen. So the equivalent is actually

```
Dir.exists?(dir_name) ? nil : Dir.mkdir(dir_name)
```

Comment: Thanks for suggesting the use of "unless".  I didn't realize Ruby has it.  I see that I've still carried over habits from programming in C.

Answer (score 2):

That is another way of writing an if-else.

```
Condition ? IfTrue : IfFalse
```

So,

```
Dir.exists?(dir_name) ? return : Dir.mkdir(dir_name)
```

Is the same as:

```
if Dir.exists?(dir_name)
    return
else
    Dir.mkdir(dir_name)
end
```

Comment: Thanks.  Now I see that after the question mark, the first command (before the colon) is for the true scenario, and the second command (after the colon) is the false scenario.  So the colon means "otherwise".