# refactor rails if else statement with to a single line with return?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, if-statement, refactoring

Im refactoring my older code parts, have lots of returns with multi line like:

```
if ...
 return false
else
 return true
end
```

How could one refactor to use a single line and return true or false?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I use the conditional operator (? :) in Ruby?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252936/how-do-i-use-the-conditional-operator-in-ruby)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Say `foo` is what is on the right of your `if`, then you can replace with:

```
foo ? false : true
```

This is known as the ternary operator.

Notice that in your case you could simply do:

```
!foo
```

Comment: thank you, so something like if request.env["HTTP_REFERER"] ? redirect_to :back : redirect_to root_path

Comment: `redirect_to request.referer ? :back : root_path`

Answer (score 0):

Following previous answer, but using return indeed:

```
return foo ? false : true
```