# Boolean in a view

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, view, internationalization, boolean

I have a trouble to show an result of boolean value in a view
I want to show enable and disable but show true or false

my code in index.html.slim

```
      th Active?  
          td = plan.enable
```

my code in show.html.slim

```
   p
    strong Active ?:
    = @plan.enable
```

How i can solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into a ternary. [How do I use the conditional operator (? :) in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252936/how-do-i-use-the-conditional-operator-in-ruby)

```
plan.enable? ? 'Enabled' : 'Disabled'
```

You could do something like that in your view.