# Rails + Bootstrap; disable <td> if date is past

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following in my view:

```
<td><%= check_box_tag 'checked_in', registration.id , registration.checked_in, :class => "check-in" %></td>
```

This particular check box is used to check students in, and indicates whether a student showed up for a class or not. I would like the button disabled after the class date has past. So it would look something like:

```
  <td><%= check_box_tag 'checked_in', registration.id , registration.checked_in, :class => "check-in",
if @orientation.class_date > Date.today then :disabled => "disabled" end %></td>
```

I get a syntax error "expecting keyword_end" with the above code.

Comment: Use [ternary operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252936/how-do-i-use-the-conditional-operator-in-ruby)

Comment: Yes, this works:       <td><%= check_box_tag 'checked_in', registration.id , registration.checked_in,
              :disabled => @orientation.class_date < Date.today ? true : false, :class => "check-in" %></td>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `if` statement and use this:

```
<td><%= check_box_tag 'checked_in', registration.id , registration.checked_in, 
:class => "check-in", disabled: (@orientation.class_date > Date.today) %></td>
```

When `@orientation.class_date > Date.today`, check box would be in `disabled` state otherwise `enabled`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use a helper method

```
def check_for_disable(orientation)
  true if orientation.class_date > Date.today
end


<td>
  <%= check_box_tag 'checked_in', registration.id , registration.checked_in, :class => "check-in", :disabled => check_for_disable(@orientation)%>
</td>
```