# What is this '?' operator in #map doing?

Tags: ruby, dictionary, operator-keyword

Looking over this bit of code here:

```
class Book
  def title
    @title
  end

  def title=(title)
    @title = titlieze(title)
  end

  private
  def titlieze(title)
    stop_words = %w(and in the of a an)
    title.capitalize.split.map{|w| stop_words.include?(w) ? w : w.capitalize}.join(' ')
  end
end
```

I am very confused about what is going on with the `?` after the `include?` in `#map` - is this an operator or a method shortcut?

Also wondering what exactly the `:` is called in this case, and what it does.

Thanks!

Comment: It is the [ternary operator](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4252936/119527).

Comment: Well, it's *a* ternary operator, specifically the conditional operator.

Answer (score 2):

It's a ternary operator. It signifies a [ternary operation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation), which acts essentially as an if-else statement. So this:

```
stop_words.include?(w) ? w : w.capitalize
```

Essentially becomes this:

```
if stop_words.include?(w)
    return w
else
    return w.capitalize
end
```

Here's how I think of a ternary operation:

```
(<if condition>) ? <thing to do if true> : <thing to do if false>
```

Comment: "turnery" != "ternary"