# How to call local variable value in a method through a parameter?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails app I have this (rather silly) method:

```
def my_method(param)

  foo = "hey"
  bar = "ho"

  if param == :foo
    return foo
  elsif param == :bar
    return bar
  end

end
```

I don't like the `if/else` block, though.

Is there a simpler way to return the value of the local variable `foo` if `:foo` is provided as a parameter?

Or will I have to use an array or a hash here?

Comment: I think you're looking for how to use a ternary operator in ruby, look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252936/how-do-i-use-the-conditional-operator-in-ruby

Comment: It's not a good use of a ternary statement because there are two possible values for `param`, resulting in a convoluted/multiple ternary. Those are used in Perl and C, but eschewed in Ruby.

Comment: You are returning `nil` if `param` is neither `:foo` nor `:bar`. Is that your intent, or are those two symbols the only possible values of param? Also, I suggest you remove the Rails tag. (Some users may miss your questions because they've filtered out Rails' questions; others, interested only in Rails questions, will be disappointed that there's no Rails' content.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Hash:

```
def my_method(param)
 objs = {
  foo: "hey",
  bar: "ho"
 }
 objs[param]
end
```

Answer (score 3):

If you're using the very latest Ruby, you can use [`binding.local_variable_get(param)`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Binding.html#method-i-local_variable_get). A hash seems cleaner to me, but your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 2):

This should look simpler, don't think introducing a new data structure is required:

```
def my_method(param)
  return 'hey' if param == :foo
  return 'ho'  if param == :bar
end
```

Answer (score 1):

This is really a good time to use a `case` statement:

```
def my_method(param)

  case param
  when :foo
    'hey'
  when :bar
    'ho'
  else
    # what do you want to do here?
  end

end
```

Something to consider is, you're using an `if`/`elseif`, but what happens if neither of those hit? Do you want to return nil, or trap an error? As you look around in other people's code, you'll sometimes find long chains of `if`/`elseif` tests, with no final `else`, which opens up a potential logic error and can result in a hard-to-find bug.