# Exclamation points before a variable in Ruby

Tags: ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

going through ruby monk and once in a while they throw out a code from the left field with unfamiliar syntaxes:

```
 def compute(xyz)
   return nil unless xyz
   xyz.map {|a,b| !b.nil? ? a + b : a}
 end
```

Can somebody explain these three uses?
1) The exclamation before the object
2) The additional question mark 3) The colon usage within the lambda

Comment: The `!` is just `'not`'.  `!b.nil? ? a + b : a` (a "ternary" operation) is shorthand for `if !b.nil?; a+b; else; b; end`, which is better expressed `if b.nil?; a; else; a+b; end`.

Comment: `! - not` `? - istrueorfalse` `a+b : a -- options`. 

This `!b.nil? ? a + b : a` is basically called ternary operation.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I'd disagree; I think a ternary makes a lot more sense here, e.g., `b.nil? ? a : a+b` is quite a bit easier to reason about, IMO.

Comment: @Xavier Some basic Ruby operator and naming convention research would clear all of this up immediately. Plus it's technically a block, not a lambda (e.g., lambdas are objects, blocks are a syntactical element, etc.)

Comment: @DaveNewton In my opinion `if b.nil? then a else a+b end` makes even more sense for non-programmer. Well, in most cases it is matter of tastes. I explained other case here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/27882720/2597260

Comment: @DaveNewton , we do not disagree. I just meant that if you go with `if..end`, I would prefer `if b.nil?...` to `if !b.nil?...`. I would use the ternary operation, but with `b.nil?...`.

Comment: @DarekNędza By definition if you're writing code you're a programmer. Short ternaries are almost more readable then extra keywords, but since it's a matter of opinion, we'll have to agree to disagree.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I think you meant me; I misunderstood the point you were making :) Sorry!

Comment: @DaveNewton I guess a term "non-programmer" was bad. If you are a beginner programmer or you programmed in a verbose language like Pascal or Ada, `if...end`-like syntax will make more sense to you. `>:``<:@.odd` - this is an example from J language. It is like "short ternaries" (2 arguments and not verbose syntax). J support more verbose syntax. Previous example may look something like this(`\n` as a newline): `if. odd n \n do. <: n \n else. >: n end.`. I think most programmers are will understand 2nd example. The same goes for `if..end` vs `?:`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`!` is a just a not operator.

`b.nil?` is a method that checks the value for b is nil or not. Returns a boolean.

`!b.nil? ? a + b : a` is a ternary operation is action. It works like this :

```
if_this_is_a_true_value ? then_the_result_is_this : else_it_is_this
```

which is equivalent of saying

```
if a then b else c end
```

So relating with above statement if `!b.nil?` is `true` answer is `a+b` else it is `a`.

Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252936/how-do-i-use-the-conditional-operator-in-ruby)

Comment: @Xavier Glad i could be of help. Please accept the answer so as to remove it from list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 2):

1)
`!`, negations - it changes every object except `nil` and `false`  to false (other objects into `true`)
2) `name?` should return false(`false` and `nil`) or true value (everything else). In most cases it will be `true` or `false` objects.
Methods with with `?` at the end suggest that they are predicates. In your example `nil?` checks if object is nil. In other language you may find something like this: `is_nil`.
Other examples:

```
[].empty? # true 
3.zero? # false
0.zero? # true
```

3) The colon in your example is part of [a ternary if](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:).

```
'cond' ? 'true value' : 'false value'
```

is similar to:

```
if 'cond'
'true value'
else
'false value'
end
```

One difference between `?:` and `if else` is precedence:

```
def foo a
a # just return a
end
foo 2 ? 3 : 4
# => 3
foo if 2 then 3 else 4 end
# error
```

In the last example Ruby wanted to run `function1 if condition` but it found `function if condition #some garbage`, so Ruby raised an error.

Answer (score 0):

1. The exclamation before the object :

   !x means negation of x, if x is true, then !x means false and vice-versa
2. The additional question mark :

   x ? y : z

   means that if x is true, then return y, else return z
3. The colon usage within the lambda

   I explained in the 2. above