# What does "!" symbol mean in Ruby language

Tags: ruby, symbols

For example: what is this saying:

```
  if !result[movie[:studio]]
    result[movie[:studio]] = movie[:worldwide_gross]
  else
    result[movie[:studio]] += movie[:worldwide_gross]
  end
  i += 1
end
```

This is a solution to manipulating an NDS, or rather getting some information from an NDS and I can't seem to find what the `!result` means.

Comment: result was a locally defined variable in the method, a hash, that is being called on to collect the amount of money what the keys point to have earned

Comment: Same as any other language, negation. This code could be written more clearly because you can omit the `!` operator and swap the blocks.

Comment: `!result` means "not result", or "if result is false"

Comment: got it, not sure why i wasn't finding that in searches.  thanks!

Comment: I googled "ruby exclamation mark". The second hit was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27882546/exclamation-points-before-a-variable-in-ruby), which answers your question. Did you research your question before asking?

Comment: This is covered in Ruby tutorials.

Comment: That's [`BasicObject#!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/BasicObject.html#method-i-21) – it returns `true` if the object is `false` or `nil`, and `false` otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

The `!` negates the element. So if `result[movie[:studio]]` is truthy then `!result[movie[:studio]]` is the opposite, falsy. Your conditional statement is basically saying that if there is no value for the `studio` key then give it a value of `movie[:worldwide_gross]`, otherwise add to the current value.

If you do not like the `!` you could consider using `unless` instead or swap the order of the conditional.

```
if result[movie[:studio]]
  result[movie[:studio]] += movie[:worldwide_gross]
else
  result[movie[:studio]] = movie[:worldwide_gross]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

! negates the element as it was already mentioned.

So, !true => false

So if you do

```
if !hungry 
 do x
end
```

You will execute X if you are *not* hungry.

It might also be used on null. So you can use it to check if "not null". This might be the use case that you're seeing.