# Need a ruby block explained

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was wondering if anyone could explain to me what the

> ?  w : w.capitalize

block means in:

`def titlieze(title)
    stop_words = %w(and in the of a an)
    title.capitalize.split.map{|w| stop_words.include?(w) ? w : w.capitalize}.join(' ')
  end`

Any help is very much appreciated... Thank you in advance.

Comment: This [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252936/how-do-i-use-the-conditional-operator-in-ruby) explains this ternary opertor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually in english grammar if we upcase first letter of every word in a sentence then we leave these words still in small letters

Words: and, in, the, of, a, an

So in titlieze method of ruby it is just making sure to ignore these words from the given sentence. So the below particular condition is just an IF ELSE and nothing else

stop_words.include?(w) ? w : w.capitalize

This means if w (the word being processed) exists in the array of ignore words stop_words (and, in, the, of, a, an) then just let it be in small case else upcase the first letter of the word.

Answer (score 1):

It's a [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Ruby) right there. This:

```
stop_words.include?(w) ? w : w.capitalize
```

Means the same as:

```
if stop_words.include?(w)
  w
else
  w.capitalize
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Tiago another wonderful explanation!!

Answer (score 0):

It's a [Ternary Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:).

For each word `w` in the `title`, if `w` is included in `stop_words` return `w` else capitalize `w` and return it to the mapper.