# Destructive map method with control flow returns unexpected nils

Tags: arrays, ruby

When I run this, it correctly changes the `3` in `array` to `"blue"`, but it changes all other elements to `nil`.

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
array.map! do |number|
  if number == 3
    array[number] = "blue"
  end
end
```

Since I introduced the `if` statement, I expect it to leave everything else alone. Can someone explain why that's happening and how to get it to only modify the element isolated with the `if` statement?

Answer (score 3):

When you run `map!` it:

> Invokes the given block once for each element of self, replacing the
>   element with the value returned by the block.

So when the number doesn't match 3 the block is returning `nil` - when it is 3 you actually don't need the assignment you're using, having simply `"blue"` would have the same effect.

This should accomplish what you're trying to do:

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
array.map! do |number|
    number == 3 ? "blue" : number
end
```

See http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map-21

Comment: Could you please explain that syntax in line 3?

Comment: A [ternary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#Ruby) is shorthand for an if else block (i.e. the above returns `"blue"` if `number==3` otherwise returns `number`). See also this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252936/how-do-i-use-the-conditional-operator-in-ruby).

Comment: Personally, I find `if number == 3 then 'blue' else number end` more readable.