# Setting Cron using chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I have a question about ruby/chef, I am creating a recipe that will setup a cron job once we chef-client the node and I am getting a syntax error when I run my kitchen test

The following block of code is part of my recipe

```
  action node["hadoop_temp"]["scripts"]["cron"]["clean_temp"]["enabled"] = ? :create : :delete
  minute node["hadoop_temp"]["scripts"]["cron"]["clean_temp"]["minute"]
  hour node["hadoop_temp"]["scripts"]["cron"]["clean_teamp"]["hour"]
  day node["hadoop_temp"]["scripts"]["cron"]["clean_temp"]["day"]
  month node["hadoop_temp"]["scripts"]["cron"]["clean_temp"]["month"]
  weekday node["hadoop_temp"]["scripts"]["cron"]["clean_temp"]["weekday"]
```

the following block is part of my attributes.

```
  #Run the cron every day at 12AM cleans /temp
  default["hadoop_temp"]["scripts"]["cron"]["clean_temp"]["enabled"] = false
  default["hadoop_temp"]["scripts"]["cron"]["clean_temp"]["minute"] = "0"
  default["hadoop_temp"]["scripts"]["cron"]["clean_temp"]["hour"] = "0"
  default["hadoop_temp"]["scripts"]["cron"]["clean_temp"]["day"] = "*"
  default["hadoop_temp"]["scripts"]["cron"]["clean_temp"]["month"] = "*"
  default["hadoop_temp"]["scripts"]["cron"]["clean_temp"]["weekday"] = "*"
```

when I run my kitchen test I am getting the following error.

```
   SyntaxError
   -----------
   /tmp/kitchen/cache/cookbooks/hadoop_temp/recipes/clean_temp.rb:25: syntax error, unexpected '?'
   ..."hadoop_temp"]["enabled"] = ? :create : :delete
```

I do not understand boolean 100% in ruby what I want to accomplish is if the entry exist create but if in the future I want to delete I just have to switch the attribute to true.

Comment: Remove the `=` sign.

Comment: You could [learn about the ternary operator in ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252936/how-do-i-use-the-conditional-operator-in-ruby).

Comment: Thank you @StephenKing my test passed! that was easy!

Comment: Please post this as an answer

Answer (score 0):

You could learn about the ternary operator in ruby[learn about the ternary operator in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252936/how-do-i-use-the-conditional-operator-in-ruby)

I did took the = sign out of the recipe action. now it looks like:

```
    action node["hadoop_temp"]["scripts"]["cron"]["clean_temp"]["enabled"] ? :create : :delete
```

Thank you @StephenKing  the test passed