# Correct use if != nil || != "" ROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, if-statement, controller

Redirect to city_path if @city.name not equal nil and ""

If @city.name equal "" also redirect to city_path. 
How to fix it?

```
if (@city.name != nil || @city.name != "")
      redirect_to city_path
      else
      render 'index'
    end
```

Comment: Hey you can simply check `if (@city.name.present?)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In one line with [`ternary operator`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252936/how-do-i-use-the-conditional-operator-in-ruby) and [`blank?`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2/classes/Object.html#method-i-blank-3F) method:

```
@city.name.blank? ? redirect_to(city_path) : render('index')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [present?](http://apidock.com/rails/Object/present%3F) method it will handle both `nil` and `blank` values

```
if (@city.name.present?)
      redirect_to city_path
      else
      render 'index'
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use like

```
 if @city.name.present?
      redirect_to city_path
      else
      render 'index'
    end
```