# How can I continues map function after if statement in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

This is my code:

```
jobs.map do |record|
  [
    record.id,
    record.jobtitle,
    record.date,
    if (record.expired) then
      "expired"
    else
      "available"
    end
    ,
    record.views_count
  ]
```

but it show error: `syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ']'`
How can I do? Thanks for any help because i'm beginer.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a ternary statement instead:

```
jobs.map do |record|
  [
    record.id,
    record.jobtitle,
    record.date,
    (record.expired ? "expired" : "available"),
    record.views_count
  ]
```

[How do I use the conditional operator (? :) in Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252936/how-do-i-use-the-conditional-operator-in-ruby)

Comment: Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the '`then`' in your if/else statement.  Using 'then' is more for clarity on one-liner if statements.  Also, move that if/else statement outside of the array.  So:

```
jobs.map do |record|
    if (record.expired)
      x = "expired"
    else
      x = "available"
    end
  [
    record.id,
    record.jobtitle,
    record.date,
    x,
    record.views_count
  ]
```

If you like one-liners you can use the ternary operator `?` for if/else such as:   `record.expired ? x='expired' : x='available'`

Comment: Thanks you very much! :D

Answer (score 1):

I noticed this from Godwin's response, all you need is the brackets.

```
jobs.map do |record|
  [
    record.id,
    record.jobtitle,
    record.date,
    (if (record.expired) then
      "expired"
    else
      "available"
    end)
    ,
    record.views_count
  ]
```

Worked for me, hope that helps.