# Find the longest word using inject method

Tags: ruby

Find the longest word.

```
longest = %w{cat sheep bear}.inject do |memo, word|
  memo.length > word.length ? memo : word
end
```

I'm guessing that `memo` will start with the value `"cat"` since `inject` did not receive any argument. I'm also guessing that the first value for `word` will be `sheep`, followed by `word` and `bear`.

I'm not following what is going on in the block and its syntax. I would appreciate if someone could elaborate.

Answer (score 5):

**1. So I'm guessing that memo will start off with the value cat seeing as inject has no argument passed to it.**

[*Documentation says:*](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject)

> If you do not explicitly specify an initial value for memo, then the
> first element of collection is used as the initial value of memo.

**2. I'm also guessing that the first word will then be sheep..then next word, bear.**

You can use `puts` to inspect each stage bar the final assignment, but that's just the return value of the inject method:

```
longest = %w{ cat sheep bear }.inject do |memo, word|
  puts "memo is currently #{memo}", 
       "word is currently #{word}",
       "-----------------------"
  memo.length > word.length ? memo : word
end

#memo is currently cat
#word is currently sheep
#-----------------------
#memo is currently sheep
#word is currently bear
#-----------------------

longest #=> "sheep"
```

---

#### Another way

Finally another more Rubyish way to get the longest word:

```
%w{ cat sheep bear }.max_by(&:length) #=> "sheep"
```

Comment: I looked up `max_by` in the documentation. They used the the following example:

Comment: `a = %w(albatross dog horse)
a.max_by { |x| x.length }`

Comment: Which i understand..if you don't mind, could you please explain how passing `(&:length)` as argument works.  I do not understand `&:` and how it can be used as argument? thx

Comment: @codebreeze this is called [`Symbol#to_proc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Symbol.html#method-i-to_proc) and what it does is converts a given symbol to a proc similar to `Proc.new { |var| var.[method_name_from_symbol] }` so in this case `Proc.new { |var| var.length }`. It was a syntactical monkey patch that caught on and was consumed into ruby core in 1.8.7 because of it's popularity

Comment: @engineersmnky Please check my reasoning. Is `:length = Proc.new { |var| var.length}` and then one makes use of the ampersand to tell the `max_by` method not to ignore the symbol/proc?

Comment: @codebreeze `max_by` accepts a block and yields each argument to this block .`&` indicates a method call of `to_proc` e.g. `&:length` actually means `:length.to_proc`. `Symbol#to_proc` creates a proc as described above. This proc now becomes the "block" passed to `max_by` and `max_by` yields the values to this block of code. I hope this is clear

Comment: @codebreeze another interesting use of `to_proc` is `Method#to_proc` where as instead of calling the method on the yielded value the yielded value is passed to the method instead as an argument i.e. `def inspect_this(a); puts a.inspect; end` then it can be called like `['a','b','c'].each(&method(:inspect_this))` and it will pass each element to the method rather than calling the method on the element

Answer (score 1):

With `inject`, the block should return the new value for `memo`

In this case the [conditional operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252936/how-do-i-use-the-conditional-operator-in-ruby) is being used to return one of two values: either the existing value of `memo` if `memo` is longer than the current word or `word` if the current word is longer or the same length. i.e. it's a way of working through the list of words maintaining the longest word so far in `memo` (or most recently seen word when the lengths are tied.)

Then at the end `inject` returns the final value of `memo`.

Comment: Ahh i see.  I didn't know about this (`? : `) operator..now it makes a lot more sense.. `if_this_is_a_true_value ? then_the_result_is_this : else_it_is_this`