# What does to_s with a colon do?

Tags: ruby

I am just wondering what happens to an object when to_s is applied to it with a colon? It is supposed to turn a single letter string into a symbol for a card game. Could someone explain if that is correct? Thanks! Here's an example:

```
def to_s
    revealed? ? value.to_s : " "
end
```

Comment: Please, post text as text, not as photographs of text. This is a website for programmers, not photographers. We want to copy&paste&run your code, not critique your use of color and perspective. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2988 https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thank you for the correction! I apologize as I am new to the site, won't happen again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you referring to the [ternary operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4252936/how-do-i-use-the-conditional-operator-in-ruby)?

It's the same as:

```rb
if revealed?
  value.to_s
else
 " "
end
```

Comment: Hey Balastrong, thanks for answering so promptly! Ohhh I see! I did not realize you could add an else argument with the ternary operator, thanks so much!!

Comment: You're welcome ^^

Answer (score 0):

This is the ternary operator.

```
condition ? expression-to-evaluate-if-true : expression-to-evaluate-if-false
```

Your example is equivalent to:

```
def to_s
    if revealed?
        value.to_s
    else
        " "
    end
end
```

In other words, the `? :` construct has nothing specifically to do with `to_s`.

Comment: Yes, I understand now! I had assumed ":" belonged to "to_s", and did not realize that it was equivalent to an else statement for the ternary operator. Thanks Chris!

Comment: Excellent. It's a nice concise way of writing expressions like this, but be careful and use it judiciously. If you have to ask yourself if you should be using it vs regular if/else, the answer is probably "no."

Comment: Gotcha, thanks so much for the tip! I'll keep that in mind